# Sending Cookie via cURL (CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE) not working - Salesforce streaming API

Tags: php, curl, cookies, salesforce

I am having trouble trying to send a Cookie via cURL. The specific case scenario is related to Salesforce streaming API but I think it applies to similar PHP situations.

This is the issue, there are 2 requests done, the first one receives a cookie named `BAYEUX_BROWSER` and uses `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` to store the cookie in the server; the second request uses the stored cookie to set a session.

This is the snippet of the first request:

```php
$cookie_filename = '/some/patch/cookies.txt';

$ch = curl_init();
// cURL cookie options being set
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $filename);
```

After the request is made, the file `cookies.txt` is created successfully, it also contains the `BAYEUX_BROWSER` cookie inside, here is an example of the returned cookies:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

xxx.my.salesforce.com   FALSE   /cometd/    TRUE    0   BAYEUX_BROWSER  e38bvb418bj8bztzkeaan2wx18y3
#HttpOnly_xxx.my.salesforce.com FALSE   /cometd/    FALSE   0   t   !0vaFlJER5UsrfIGrfKp9YI2pARkJi5YS8O/yCf8GE+6HiX+CvWWacnC3MzF+OXsuC3USJWIP3jamDQ==
.salesforce.com TRUE    /   FALSE   1629832267  BrowserId   kGpyG-Y9EeqF7jOgs3LDaA
xxx.my.salesforce.com   FALSE   /   FALSE   1598388400  sfdc-stream !jH2NPGTjjg64odBoo4aJz7403s94D3xXnkFrzyha9kaRQGVKxQfnpfplyv8vwVzqy4p9godcH/z7O1A=
```

The second request uses `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` to set the location of the cookies file and make the request using them:

```php
$cookie_filename = '/some/patch/cookies.txt';

$ch = curl_init();
// cURL cookie options being set
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $filename);
```

The issue here is that the response from Salesforce is that the `BAYEUX_BROWSER` cookie is not present in the request, here is the exact response:

```
400::Client xxxx has established a session, but no BAYEUX_BROWSER cookie present
```

I have been trying for hours now to change and play with different cURL options to see if I can enable the cookie but had no luck.

I am not sure if I need to change the COOKIE format, or if I am missing something, I honestly don't know at this point.

Any one had a similar issue or knows what is wrong with my code?

Comment: So just to get the obvious out of the way, is your second request to `xxx.my.salesforce.com` at the path `/cometd/`?

Comment: Also, are you calling `curl_close` on your first run before you open the second connection? I believe that the cookies aren't written until after that completes.

Comment: Yes, the connections are being closed between requests, the cookies are created before the second request, I have verified this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this issue solved using the **Guzzle** package (https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle) instead of **cURL**.

```php
$cookie_filename = '/some/patch/cookies.json';
$jar = new \GuzzleHttp\Cookie\FileCookieJar( $filename, true );
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

// First response
$response = $client->request( 'POST', $url1, [
    'headers' => [...],
    'cookies' => $jar,
    'form_params' => ['message' => json_encode( $message )], 
] );

if ( $response->getStatusCode() === 200 ) {
    $response = json_decode( (string)$response->getBody() );
    // Set client ID
    $response = $client->request( 'POST', $url2, [
        'headers' => [...],
        'cookies' => $jar,
        'form_params' => ['message' => json_encode( $message )], 
    ] ); 
}
```